# How to reference to div id without clicking the href link?

Tags: java, python, html

I am trying to render a web-page using streamlit in python where I want to automatically scroll to a particular section of a page. I am no expert in html or java so I would appreciate a solution with examples.

So I have a div at the bottom of the page such as,

```
st.markdown("<div id='linkto_bot'></div>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

and I have this html code at the top,

```
st.markdown("<a href='#linkto_bot'>Link to bottom</a>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

which renders a link as shown,

[image]

upon the clicking the link I get scrolled to the section where the `div` is was added.

Is there a possibility to get redirected to the `div` without having to click to on the link?

I tried the following but in vain:

1. `st.markdown("a href='#linkto_bot', unsafe_allow_html=True)`  saw this somewhere on the net but did not work.
2. Using javascript,

```
html_string = '''
<script language="javascript">
    location.href = "#";
    location.href = "#linkto_bot";
</script>
'''
components.html(html_string)
```

This did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript function `scrollIntoView()`

```
document.getElementById('linkto_bot').scrollIntoView();
```